# How to detect overflow after adding multiple binary numbers in 2C?

Tags: binary, boolean, addition, digital, boolean-algebra

Let's say I want to add 4 binary numbers in 2's Complement: a+b+c+d. I have a circuit that can add 2 binary numbers at a time, and that detects whether overflow has occurred for the corresponding sum (by using XOR with the last carry bits).

When adding multiple numbers in 2's Complement, it is possible that the intermediate sums overflow, while the final result does not. For example:

4 + 5 + (-6) expressed with 4 bits and C2:

```
0100 +
0101
====
1001 (-7 : overflow)

1001 +
1010
====
0011 (3, the correct result)
```

My question is: how can I know, when adding 4 binary numbers with N bits, whether the final result overflows or not? Is there any logical expression or circuit that can automatically detect when overflow occurs?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, 0100 + 0101, represented with 4 bits, gives the hardware result of 1001.
It is now up to you how you interpret these bits.
If you interpret them as 2’s complement integers, the result is wrong (decimal -7, overflow).
If you interpret them as unsigned integers, the result is correct (decimal 9).
If you add then 1010, you have to think about how to interpret these bits.
Unsigned, they are decimal 10, 2’s complement, they are decimal -6.
Still, it is up to you, how you interpret the result. It is 0011 plus a carry bit, since 1001 + 1010 gives 10011.
Thus the problem arises because you change the interpretation of the bits during the computation.
This cannot be handled by any logical expression or circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have specified the fact that I am interpreting the numbers only as in 2's complement representation. I am not changing the interpretation of the results at any steps. The example's purpose was to demonstrate the statement: "when adding more than 2 binary numbers with N bits, it is possible that the final result is correct (does not overflow), even if intermediate sums might overflow".

So the problem is: when adding multiple binary numbers in 2's complement, how can one determine whether the final result actually overflows, or is within range?

Comment: If you interpret all numbers only as 2’s complement, you have 4 + 5 = -7 which is obviously wrong, as is -7 + -6 = 3. To me, it make no sense at all to ask whether the addition of 2 wrong results gives a correct result.

Comment: It is a property of numbers in 2's Complement, when adding more than 2 numbers (each having the same number of bits), the final result may be correct EVEN THOUGH intermediate sums overflow and are not correct.

Adding a+b+c, where the 3 operands all have N bits, sum1=a+b might overflow, sum2=sum1+c might overflow as well, but the result of sum2 might be correct if the result is within the range [-2^(N-1) ; ( 2^(N-1) ) - 1], even though the result of sum1 is NOT within the specified range.

Comment: You are right, but only if you do not interpret the immediate result as 2's complement. -7 + -6 is definitively not 3.